# Fib. sequences/ Combintorics

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone please help me prove the following: $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n-k\choose k}=F_{n+1}$. I already know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\choose 2k}=F_{n+1}$, but I don't know how to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\choose 2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n-k\choose k}=F_{n+1}$

Comment: What is your definition of $F_n$? If fixed, such identity has a straightfoward combinatorial proof by recalling that the number of binary strings with length $n$ and no adjacent $1$s is $F_{n+2}$.

Comment: Simple manipulations of the summations does it. No combinatorics needed.

Comment: @martycohen: that works if you assume that the OP started with the right identity, which is not the case.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: I see that. However, since OP already knows the value of the second sum, proving that the first sum equals the second sum does evaluate the first sum.

Comment: @martycohen: the point is that the first sum *is not* $F_{n+1}$, it equals $F_{2n+1}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: I don't think so. In my answer I show that the index in the first sum really only goes to $n$ because the terms with $k > n$ are $\binom{2n-k}{k}$ are zero since $k > 2n-k$ for $k > n$.

Comment: @martycohen: there is a misunderstanding here. I am not saying that reindexing does not work or that the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n-k}{k}$ differs from zero for $k>n$, I am simply saying that we cannot prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n-k}{k}$ equals $F_{n+1}$ because that is not true, it equals $F_{2n+1}$, as combinatorics clearly shows.

Answer (score 2):

I'll play and see what happens.

You want to show that
$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n-k\choose k}=F_{n+1}
$.

First of all,
if $k > n$
then
$k > 2n-k$.
Therefore
$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n-k\choose k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n-k\choose k}
$.

Next,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n-k\choose k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n-k\choose (2n-k)-k}
\qquad\binom{a}{b} = \binom{a}{a-b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n-k\choose 2n-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n-(n-k)\choose 2n-2(n-k)}
\qquad\text{Reverse order of summation: } k \to n-k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\choose 2k}\\
\end{array}
$

and since you know that
$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\choose 2k}=F_{n+1}
$
we are done.

Note that this shows that
$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\choose 2k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n-k\choose k}
$
without any evaluation of
what the sums actually are.

Comment: The second sum $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{2k}$ is also $F_{2n+1}$, not $F_{n+1}$...

Comment: OK. I just proved the two sums equal without knowing what they were.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the Fibonacci number $F_n$ is defined as the $n$-th term of the sequence such that $F_0=0,F_1=1$, $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$.

**Lemma**. The number of strings over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ with length $m$ and no adjacent $1$s is $F_{m+2}$.

**Proof**. A valid string either starts with a $0$ followed by a valid string with $m-1$ characters, or with $10$ followed by a valid string with $m-2$ characters. Induction finishes the proof.

**Observation**. We may count the valid strings, according to their number of $1$s, through [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Let $m=2n-1$. If we have $k$ characters $1$, we have $2n-1-k$ characters zero, and a valid string with $k$ characters $1$ can be constructed by inserting them in the spaces between $2n-1-k$ consecutive zeroes, at the end or at the beginning, i.e. in $2n-k$ positions. It follows that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n-k}{k} = F_{\color{red}{2n+1}}.$$